# Maven POM-Editor: Dependency Graph missing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In Eclipse Helios I have the nice feature of a dependency graph inside the maven pom editor.
[image]

But in later installations (Helios-sr2 and Indigo) this feature is missing. Does anybody know how to activate this? (I'm using OSX, 64bit cocoa)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This has been removed from m2e 1.0 (previously it was available if you selected 'show advanced editors', but that option is now gone too). The developers behind it have stated that the dependency graph never worked that well with more than a handful of dependencies and the dependency hierarchy view works better anyway.

Here is one of the messages from m2e-users about this:

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg00769.html

Comment: Can't seem to get the dependency hierarchy view with the Indigo SR2

Answer (score 2):

The Dependency graph is still available! At least in Indigo and Helios-SR2 you can activate the graph in the Eclipse settings: `Maven - POM Editor - Show advanced tabs in the POM editor`.

Comment: as steted by Spencer Uresk, this option is gone in m2e 1.0