# Dependency hierarchy view for maven in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

Can't seem to get the dependency hierarchy view with the latest version of eclipse (Indigo SR2). This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475927/maven-pom-editor-dependency-graph-missing) from almost a year ago indicates that the dependency graph is no longer supported but that the dependency hierarchy should be working

Thanks

sfk

[image: Update : screenshot upload]

Comment: What exactly your problem is about? Dependency Hierarchy view works for me well with same Eclipse version.

Comment: attached a screenshot. I can't get it to work for me. Also have adt and m2e (for android) installed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure to open the `pom.xml` file using the *Maven POM Editor*. Right-click the file, then select *Open With > Maven POM Editor*. This should give you the expected editor with the option to view the dependencies and the dependency hierarchy.

Please see the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]