# How version of lib defined in classpath?

Tags: java, maven

i have hirarhy of modules. 
I set up version of hibernate-validator as 6.1.5.Final
But when i build project version of library another 
maven dependencies: tree ouput

```
org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.4.Final:compile
```

I can not understand how it works.

I put all dependency tree here https://paste2.org/CwB2H4W2

Comment: could you post the relevant pom.xml?

Comment: @JoostPapendorp added dependency tree output

Comment: Thank you for posting the tree listing, Dimitry. I can see that domain pulls in org.hibernate:hibernate-validator version 5.3.4.
However, to help you solve this, could you post the *pom.xml* file itself?

Answer (score 0):

Problems with dependencies should always bring you to the "Dependency Hierarchy" Tab of your POM.xml. There you will see your projects dependencies, and dependencies of that dependencies.

If I had to guess I'd say there you will find a module providing the dependency you think you don't use.

Further information to maybe change this:
First declared dependencies get used first. So if you define your dependency before the Module that brings the other dependency in, Maven should select yours.

Comment: What do you mean by "Dependency Hierarchy Tab of your POM.xml"? The POM.xml is a file. Files don't have "tabs".

Comment: @DodgyCodeException For sure you are right, but Maven has a built in plugin maven-dependency-plugin to show dependency-trees, easier to use are functions of IDEs like eclipse for example that shows this, and more, as easy overview. Following gives an instruction to that topic in eclipse, showing those Editortabs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517055/dependency-hierarchy-view-for-maven-in-eclipse-indigo

Comment: @JanUhlig  added frull dependency tree