# Represent a Maven multi module project in a form of graph

Tags: maven, multi-module

Context : I work for a new project. It is a maven multi module project (70 modules).

I am trying to realize a purpose of each module and dependecies between them. Is there are any tool that may represent this information in a form of graph?

What have I tried: I found [Dependecy Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475927/maven-pom-editor-dependency-graph-missing) functionality of m2e plugin that is unfortunately not available in Eclipse Luna. In any case it is not a good option for me, I wan't see any dependent JARs, only modules.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a graph of the dependency between all modules of a Maven project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084669/how-to-generate-a-graph-of-the-dependency-between-all-modules-of-a-maven-project)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe have a look at [depgraph](https://github.com/ferstl/depgraph-maven-plugin). It is possible to select by groupId so you should be able to generate a useful diagram.