# How to remove invalid version in dependecies

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven to compile project.

here is result of dependency:tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ tournament-system-web ---
[INFO] org.toursys:tournament-system-web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.toursys:tournament-system-processor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.toursys:tournament-system-repository:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.sqlproc:sql-processor:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.antlr:ST4:jar:4.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.sqlproc:sql-processor-spring:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.1.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |        \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-core:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.wicket:wicket-request:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-spring:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.wicket:wicket-ioc:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] |     \- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |        \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-datetime:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-extensions:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.wicketstuff:wicketstuff-minis:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.wicket:wicket:pom:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:runtime
[INFO] \- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.20:compile
```

problem is when I look into generated war there is two version of wicket. 1.5.5 and 1.5.8 and I dont know why there is still older version. I dont have it in dependency. How I can remove it or find why there is still this library ?

Comment: Have you done a clean? Sometimes you have old jars hanging around in the target directory.

Comment: yes I always do mvn clean install

Answer (score 0):

You should exlude `wicket-1.5.5` which comes as dependency of another package.
Dependency exclusion is described [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).

Comment: yea but I dont know which dependecy to exclude

Comment: you should first generate dependency graph. Described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084669/how-to-generate-a-graph-of-the-dependency-between-all-modules-of-a-maven-project