# A visual graph of all dependencies modelled by Maven Central

Tags: java, maven, maven-central

A [previous question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4084669/521799) has shown that it is possible to plot a graph of all modules within a Maven managed project.

I'm wondering if anyone has done and published an authoritative visual representation of all dependencies managed by Maven Central?

Comment: Sounds like a fun-visualization project. Perhaps something that can be run via circos (though the genetic-engineering terminology use in circos makes it unnecessarily complicated).

Comment: @kabram: I guess this can be achieved in many ways. Those circos graphs look adequate. I've seen similar graphs before in http://d3js.org/ To keep this from being an open-ended question, I'm currently mostly interested in (possibly) existing implementations.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain?

Comment: Update: I've written some code since your post that goes to Maven central and extracts all poms, performs some cleanup and then can extract dependencies. It stores results in a mongodb collection. I hope in the near future to run the data extraction fully and then generate a graph from it.

Comment: @kabram: Would be nice to publish your work as open source!

Comment: Good idea. Will do so in the next few days.

Answer (score 3):

there exists a tool which could help achieving your goal, it is called **Pom Explorer**.

You can find the website here : [github.com/ltearno/pom-explorer](https://github.com/ltearno/pom-explorer)

It is a tool to work on a graph of maven projects. As a teaser i can say that on my machine it analyzes 4000 pom.xml files in 4 seconds. Then many functionnalities are provided above the analysed pom graph :

- dependency analysis (who depends on GAV, which gavs this GAV depends on, with transitivity),
- resolution (pom explorer knows where are defined properties, it manages dependencies and bom imports),
- manipulation (you can use it to transform you pom graph, let's say if you want many projects to use a new version of a dependency),
- build (pom explorer analyses your pom graph and knows in which order they should be built, then it builds everything ! it can even watch your projects directories for change),
- exporting (today there is CSV and a GRAPHML exports),
- visualization (pom explorer can show you an interactive 3D customizable visualization of your projects graph).

It is in active development right now so don't hesitate to try it, report bugs and ask for useful features ! The documentation is also not complete yet, so again don't hesitate to ask !

Thanks