# List all artifacts in a Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, maven-indexer

Aether has a function to get all versions of a given artifact, as follows:

```
org.sonatype.aether.impl.VersionRangeResolver.resolveVersionRange( 
    RepositorySystemSession session, 
    VersionRangeRequest request )
```

Is there a aether function to list *all* the artifacts in a repository?

Or how to get that list?

Note: I am aware that most Maven repositories offer a human-readable index that you could parse and crawl. This is not a safe solution, just a workaround, and I am not looking for this type of solution.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14689482/521799

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty much an official answer of "no" is [this answer](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aether-users/msg00047.html) to "list artifacts with Aether?":

> No.
>
> These kind of queries for are a job for the [Maven Indexer](http://maven.apache.org/maven-indexer/).

from [Benjamin Bentmann](http://projects.eclipse.org/content/benjamin-bentmann-project-lead-aether).

You may find that the [Maven Indexer](https://github.com/apache/maven-indexer) is exactly what you need, however.

Comment: The current stable version of the maven-indexer is from 2013 and it doesn't work together with maven-core 3.2.X. And the ticket system on that repo is closed, which is not very friendly.