# How to analize/visualize OSGi, maven dependencies

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, osgi, tycho, nodeclipse

I am trying to build [Aptana studio](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/studio3) using Maven/Tycho.

It has a lot of Eclipse plugins and I would like to exclude some of them from the build. However the excluded plugins may be required by other plugins.

**How to see what plugins are dependent on the current plugin? Is the some tools to visualize dependencies in a [directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph)?**

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084669/how-to-generate-a-graph-of-the-dependency-between-all-modules-of-a-maven-project

Comment: @Paul: The status update you edited into the question should have been posted as a comment instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Plugin Dependencies View which comes with PDE has a button (two-to-one graph) to show plugins depending on the focused plugin.

If you want to see the full picture, then you will need to install the [PDE Incubator Dependency Visualization](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/dependency-visualization/) (update site link included). Note this often gets quickly unreadable.

UPDATE by Paul

Update site `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/pde/incubator/visualization/site`
Need to uncheck "Group items by category" for item to appear.
It is version 0.5.0.20090415
So it is almost 5 years old and is unlikely to ever graduate from incubator.

Added Marketplace entry: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pde-incubator-dependency-visualization

Comment: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/pde/incubator/visualization/site gives me 404. Any updated link?

Comment: Not a direct one. I have found the Git repository for this plugin (here: http://git.eclipse.org/c/pde/eclipse.pde.incubator.git/tree/visualization/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.visualization.dependency), but you would have to build it yourself...

Comment: Thanks Paul for the Marketplace link!