# HIbernate JPA caused by incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.Proxy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, proxy

`HIbernate JPA` caused by incompatible with `javassist.util.proxy.Proxy`.

**Code**

```
public class EntityA {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entityB_id")
    private EntityB entityB;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entityC_id")
    private EntityC entityC;
}

String sql = "select o from EntityA o "
        + "left outer join o.entityB as o1 ";
final TypedQuery<EntityA> query = getEm().createQuery(sql, EntityA.class);

final List<EntityA> result = query.getResultList();
```

**Questions**

When ran above query will get below exception, did anyone have an idea?

My query didn't involved the "EntityC", why the exception will throw with regarding the EntityC at getResultList() method?

**Exception**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: xxx.xx.xx.EntityC_$$_javassist_105 incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxy(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:148)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.getProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:73)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:758)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4419)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:334)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:260)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1053)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:980)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:714)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:502)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:137)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1112)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:969)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:917)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:348)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2550)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2366)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2361)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:198)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1230)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:268)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor213.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:368)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.getResultList(Unknown Source)
at com.cimb.module.payment.bill.ce.dao.CEMYCCPayeeAccessBean.findNormalByPayeeNameKeyword(CEMYCCPayeeAccessBean.java:59)
at com.cimb.module.payment.bill.atom.RetrieveBillerByKeywordMYAtom.performNormalBillerSearch(RetrieveBillerByKeywordMYAtom.java:58)
at com.cimb.module.payment.bill.atom.RetrieveBillerByKeywordMYAtom.proceedNextStep(RetrieveBillerByKeywordMYAtom.java:45)
at core.logic.DefaultLogicProcessor.process(DefaultLogicProcessor.java:78)
... 94 more
```

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with your libraries on the class path. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481540/hibernate-exception-javassist-0-cannot-be-cast-to-javassist-util-proxy-proxy

Comment: I don't think is the libraries issue. I saw many post was regarding java.lang.ClassCastException: xxxx **cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy**, but not this **incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.Proxy**. It seem this associattion force me to join all the entities declare at the parent entity.

Comment: Probably the library has different versions and may create another message for the `ClassCastException` depending on its version. However, it is still likely you are facing the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is caused by the `getResultList()` call?

Comment: yes, pretty sure. It shown from the stack trace where is point the line number at this "final List<EntityA> result = query.getResultList();"

Comment: @zack I face this issue. Getting from .getResultList();, How did you overcome? I use Hibernate 5.2.4

Comment: @Ratha For my case, because I'm using Websphere8.5 as AppServer, WAS8.5 bundle javassist lib inside the server cause it conflict with the Hibernate's javassist version. You can try by troubleshoot the classloader loading with your environment make sure no lib was conflict with the server jre or server runtime lib

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have encountered this problem too.
After some research here is my conclusion:

1. javassist is too old or missing
   For older Spring version, you have to add / update your javassist.
   You can get the latest from the Maven repositorty.
   [Link Here!](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist)
2. If you are getting `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` error, it is due to you are trying to do lazy load after your connection has been closed. You may need to add a **`@Transactional`** annotation in your service / controller (depending on your project's design), in either class level or method level.