# javassist_16 casting error on entities in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I get javassist_16 cannot be cast to proxy error like below when using the following environment

1. java - 1.8.0_171
2. spring MVC-  4.0.6.Release
3. Hibernate - 4.3.6.Final

The application has been deployed in Tomcat 8.5.31 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I have already added javaassist dependency in my gradle build but that does not solve my issue.

> Exception :
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: {ClassName}_$$_javassist_16 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
>           at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxy(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.getProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:771) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4613) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:989) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:716) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]

Comment: You might be facing an issue similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481540/hibernate-exception-javassist-0-cannot-be-cast-to-javassist-util-proxy-proxy)

Comment: I have solved this issue by excluding the javaassist module from the apache tiles. All works fine now.