# Looking for a way to visualize dependency structure of my multi-module pom project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin, dependency-graph

I have a pretty large project (~30 modules) and want to visualize module inter dependencies, excluding 3rd party.

It seems that existing tools simply can't handle the maven reactor. The maven dependency plugin (dependency:tree goal) knows how to generate graphml, but only per module. And if I use the append flag, it simply shoves everything to a single file, so the output is a corrupted graphml.

I also found [this tool](https://github.com/janssk1/maven-graph-plugin/wiki/Manual) but it seems that there is no way to control module granularity.

My last resort would be to parse the output of dependency:tree, but I thought I'll consult the community before this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a graph of the dependency between all modules of a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084669/how-to-generate-a-graph-of-the-dependency-between-all-modules-of-a-maven-project)

Answer (score 4):

I like [depgraph-maven-plugin](https://github.com/ferstl/depgraph-maven-plugin) to visualize dependencies in a multi-module project. To get an aggregated result in text format (like `dependency:tree`) for your modules, use:

```
mvn com.github.ferstl:depgraph-maven-plugin:aggregate -DgraphFormat=text -Dincludes=myGroupId
```

The syntax for includes is the same as with [maven-dependency-plugin includes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#includes).

It has a lot of [properties to customize the result/behavior](https://ferstl.github.io/depgraph-maven-plugin/aggregate-mojo.html). I prefer to use it together with [graphviz](https://graphviz.org/download/), so I can use the (default) graph format `dot` and let it create a `png` file in the `target` folder:

```
mvn com.github.ferstl:depgraph-maven-plugin:aggregate -DcreateImage -Dincludes=myGroupId
```

There are also other interesting [goals](https://ferstl.github.io/depgraph-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html), e.g. an `example` goal to quickly play around with the properties.

Answer (score -1):

i have actually the same situation. we have 4 big projects with ~100 pom.xml per project and dependencies between them. i had not found a good software.

now i use structure 101 (structure101.com) to show me the dependencies between them. sure, it is not maven pom.xml based, but in my case i think the problem because i have this massive count of maven project in every application is the missing software architecture.

currently i try to visualize these dependencies on class/package level and also with a deployment view (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_diagram)

i hobe this helped you a little bit.

Software i used but no tool was really good for my pom.xml count:

- https://code.google.com/p/q4e/wiki/DependencyGraphViewer
- https://code.google.com/p/maven-overview-plugin